# J2ME getDisplay() method

Tags: java, java-me, midp, midlet, lcdui

In J2ME to create the Display class object we use

```
private Display d;
d=Display.getDisplay(this);
```

What is `this` as parameter?

I know this refers to the current instance but when I write the following I get errors

```
d=Display.getDisplay(new MyClassName());
```

When I saw in book the method was written like below

```
static Display getDisplay(MIDlet midlet)
```

So then I tried this

```
MIDlet m;
d=Display.getDisplay(m);
```

But I am getting errors and I cannot even pass `new MIDlet()` as parameter since it's an abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Android says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552955/839601), `this` in **d=Display.getDisplay(this);** refers to your MIDlet.

But when you write the following you get errors

```
d=Display.getDisplay(new MyClassName());
```

It's because you try to create MIDlet by it's constructor. You would to see [MIDlet doc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#MIDlet%28%29):

> protected MIDlet()
>       Protected constructor for subclasses. The application management software is responsible for creating MIDlets and creation of MIDlets
>   is restricted. MIDlets should not attempt to create other MIDlets.
>       Throws:
>       SecurityException - unless the application management software is creating the MIDlet.

Answer (score 4):

In the code `d=Display.getDisplay(this);` , **this** refers to the Current Midlet. The Method `getDisplay()` takes one midlet argument. Take the following simple example

```
public class MyMidlet extends Midlet
{
    private Display display;

   public MyMidlet()
   {
       display = Display.getDisplay(this);  // Here this refers to the current class's Midlet
   }
}
```

Now suppose you have normal class file like below,

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Display display;
    Midlet m;

   public MyClass()
   {
       display = Display.getDisplay(m);  // You can not do this directly.
   }
}
```

if you want the above scenario then you might need to change your code some how like below,
suppose you have both the class in same package.

```
// Midlet Class 
    public class MyMidlet extends Midlet
    {
        private MyClass mycls;
        public void myMethod ()
        {
           mycls = MyClass(this); // Passing Midlet reference to MyClass's constructor.
        }
        ....
        ....
        ....
    }


// another class file 
    public class MyClass
    {
        private Display display;
        Midlet m;

       public MyClass( Midlet m )
       {
        this.m = m;
        display = Dispaly.getDisplay(m);  // Now it will work
       }
    }
```

Comment: @Android----I have only one class which is extending the MIDlet (i.e. i do not have a normal class) and i wanted to ask is there any way i can replace that "this" as parameter to the getDisplay() method. In your example you have used 2 classes which is not my case.